# How to send RequestBody correctly to PUT

Tags: javascript, kotlin, web, frontend

In my Controller file (backend) there is a PUT like this:

```
@PutMapping("/sanction")
fun putSanctionUndo(
        @RequestBody inputDTO: InputDTO
)
```

What is the correct way of sending the body from the frontend? I'm thinking in something like this:

```
  export const putSanctionUndo = async ({Id, ValidationId}) => {
      const { data } = await apiClient.put('/sanction', {
        body: {
          "Id": Id,
          "ValidationId": ValidationId,
        },
      });
   return data;
  }
```

I'm not sure if the "body" is correct. Do I need to declare is as a json or semethng?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you maybe need to stringify your body like:

```
    body: JSON.stringify({
              "Id": Id,
              "ValidationId": ValidationId,
            })
```

With fetch you will have something like this:

```
fetch(
        'URL_REST_API_ENDPOINT',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            YOUR_JSON_PROPERTIES
          }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }
      )
```